# How to get VNC security type from server with sockets on Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.x, vnc

How to create a script for Python , which will be connect to specific ip with port , and print/return , which security type VNC connection have?

```
import socket
def check(ip,port):
    vnc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    vnc.connect((ip,int(port)))
    vnc_ver = vnc.recv(12)
    print(vnc_ver)
    vnc.send(vnc_ver)
    print(vnc.recv(1024))
check("127.0.0.1","5900")
```

I just get output:"RFB 003.008"

Comment: Share the code you have written so far.

Comment: @k4ppa check my question again

Comment: @ppperry in RFB protocol specification , after client send client vnc viewer version, server must send security types, which supported by server

Comment: @ppperry  http://vncdotool.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rfbproto.html#id21
i dont use this program, because it VERY BIG overhead for my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IETF RFC 6143 (The Remote Framebuffer Protocol) defines that security handshake occurs after version handshake (see https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6143.txt paragraph 7.1.2).

In the first phase of the security handshake, the VNC server is supposed to:

- send 1 byte containing the number of supported security types
- followed by the supported security types (each security type coded on one byte)

So a Python script (similar to the one in your question) could display the supported security types that way:

```
import socket

def displaySecurityType(sec_type):
    switcher = {
        0: "Invalid",
        1: "NONE",
        2: "VNC Authentication"
    } 
    print(' security type: ' + str(sec_type) + ' (' + switcher.get(sec_type,"Not defined by IETF") +')' )

def check(ip,port):
    vnc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    vnc.connect((ip,int(port)))
    vnc_ver = vnc.recv(12)
    print(vnc_ver)
    vnc.send(vnc_ver)
    nb_sec_types = ord(vnc.recv(1))
    print("Nb security types: " + str(nb_sec_types))
    for i in xrange(0,nb_sec_types):
        sec_type = ord(vnc.recv(1))
        displaySecurityType(sec_type) 
check("127.0.0.1","5900")
```